# Can I use mutate with conditions in R?

Tags: r, string, tidyverse

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(stock_code = c("600000", "300000", "000000"), 
                 stock_price = c(10.00, 11.00, 12.00))
```

I would like to add some characters to the stock_code, the rules are:

1. if the first number of stock_code is "6"，then add".XSHG" to the stock_code, like 600000.XSHG
2. if the first number of stock _code is "0" or "3", then add".XSHE" to the stock_code, like 300000.XSHE and 000000.XSHE

I know str_sub may be helpful, but can anybody tell me how to code in tidyverse with `%>%`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `grepl` to look for a pattern and `case_when` to add conditions.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(new_stock_code = case_when(
            grepl('^6', stock_code) ~ paste0(stock_code, '.XSHG'), 
            grepl('^[30]', stock_code) ~ paste0(stock_code, '.XSHE'), 
            TRUE ~ stock_code))


#  stock_code stock_price new_stock_code
#1     600000          10    600000.XSHG
#2     300000          11    300000.XSHE
#3     000000          12    000000.XSHE
```

In base R, you can use nested `ifelse` :

```
transform(df, new_stock_code = ifelse(grepl('^6', stock_code), 
     paste0(stock_code, '.XSHG'), ifelse(grepl('^[30]', stock_code), 
     paste0(stock_code, '.XSHE'),stock_code)))
```

Comment: Both are nice. Code golf, bring `paste0` *outside* of the `case_when` and `ifelse` statements, have them return one of `'.XSHG'`, `'.XSHE'`, or `""`, and then `paste0(stock_code, ...)` to the entire `case_when`/`ifelse`.